# Getting Char From Position in C# textbox

Tags: c#, textbox

I'm trying to get 3 character from textbox -> for example: "test" and get 3 from this text.

I'm trying something like that where printer1_logo.text is another textbox where i'd like to have 4 character from textbox RefrenceNumber.

```
Printer1_Logo.Text=RefrenceNumber.GetCharFromPosition(4);
```

Errors:

```
Argument 1: cannot convert from 'int' to 'System.Drawing.Point' (CS1503) - D:\App\MainForm.cs:249,66

The best overloaded method match for 'System.Windows.Forms.TextBoxBase.GetCharFromPosition(System.Drawing.Point)' has some invalid arguments (CS1502) - D:\App\MainForm.cs:249,31
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In C#

`textBox1.Text = textBox2.Text[2].ToString()`

In VB

`textBox1.Text = textBox2.Text(2).ToString`

If you need more than 1 char

`textBox1.Text = textBox2.Text.SubString(2,2)`

Answer (score 4):

GetCharFomPosition (Position means Coordinates. isn't char index)
you can also use string as a char array for example :

```
Char  theChar = Printer1_Logo.Text[2]; // index is start at 0
```

Answer (score 1):

You can simply use **SubString** to cut out from a string:

```
string subString1 = textbox1.Text.Substring(0,3)
```